# Update timestamps every 30 seconds using setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have a list of posts like so:

```
<ul>
    <li>
       <p class="post" id="432">This is a post</p>
       <p class="timestamp">5 minutes ago</p>
    </li>
    <li>
       <p class="post" id="589">This is another post on the site</p>
       <p class="timestamp">1 hour ago</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to update the timestamp every 30 seconds (much like facebook timestamps) using `setInterval()`.

```
function update_timestamps(){


    $('.timestamp').ajax({
        type    : 'POST', 
        url     : '/ajax/refresh_timestamp', 
        data    : { 'post_id' : $(this).closest('li').find('p.post').attr('id') },          
        success : function(data){ 
            $(this).html(data);
        }
    });

}

setInterval(update_timestamps(), 30000);
```

Obviously something is wrong with my .ajax() function, or maybe I shouldn't use ajax() at all?

Comment: So what is it currently doing?

Comment: Right now, nothing is updating.

Comment: You may have a boo-boo in your call to `setInterval`. It looks like you're passing the return value of `update_timestamps` rather than a reference to the function. I think you want to do this: `setInterval(update_timestamps, 30000);`.

Comment: I think the approach needs to be rethought entirely. I'm just not sure what the best practice is.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to show only "time ago" why use ajax at all?
Just use this plugin, [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/)

Comment: Logic error. This will eventually crash the browser. If it calls update_timestamps for each element it will eventually be running the function infinitely.

Comment: +1 for the point that ajax in this case does not make sense at all :)

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really an answer to your question but... an alternative, that would mean you could avoid the ajax calls all together, would be to add the timestamp to the attribute, something like:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <p class="post" id="432">This is a post</p>
    <p class="timestamp" data-timestamp="1313649170147">5 minutes ago</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p class="post" id="589">This is another post on the site</p>
    <p class="timestamp" data-timestamp="1313649189299">1 hour ago</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then you would process your timestamps client side:

```
function updateDateTimestamps() {
  $('.timestamp').each(function(i, t) {
    var $t = $(t);
    $t.text(prettyDate($t.data('timestamp')));
  });
}
```

For an implementation of prettyDate see http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/

Then pass `updateDateTimestamps` to `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(updateDateTimestamps, 30000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is inherently wrong with your ajax function. You're just calling `setInterval` wrong:

```
setInterval(update_timestamps, 30000);
```

(notice the function reference to update_timestamps, not function call)

If you think hard, you will realize for yourself why what you did didn't work (hint: you're passing `undefined` to setInterval).

Answer (score 1):

From the [fine manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> **context**
>   This object will be made the context of all Ajax-related callbacks. By default, the context is an object that represents the ajax settings used in the call (`$.ajaxSettings` merged with the settings passed to `$.ajax`).

So your `this` in the success callback is, essentially, just the AJAX options. So either specify the right `context` option to get the `this` you're expecting or use an explicit selector:

```
success : function(data){ 
    $('.timestamp').html(data);
    setTimeout(update_timestamps, 30000);
}
```

You probably want to add an `error` callback to restart your timer if there was an error. Or use the `complete` callback for that:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('.timestamp').html(data);
},
complete: function() {
    setTimeout(update_timestamps, 30000);
}
```

Even with all that you still have a problem with `.timestamp` matching multiple things in your callbacks so you'll need to adjust your whole approach (i.e. `id` attributes on the `.timestamp` elements and an id-to-timestamp mapping in the returned data). Or just ditch the AJAX and listen to naveen.

Comment: Thanks mu. I thought something was up with the `this` in the statement, but couldn't put my finger on it.

Comment: @melee: There's still a uniqueness issue with `.timestamp` (see my update), I was going to delete this but I brought it back, noted the next problem you'll face, and told you to pay attention to naveen instead.

Comment: I'm not the OP, just a javascript enthusiast that is up too late trying to help people out :P

Comment: @melee: I'm up too late too :) Also trying to do too many things at once and one of those things should be sleeping.